# how to count days between two dates with where conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have table and it has following data:

```
USERID  NAME  DATEFROM      DATETO
1       xxx  2014-05-10     2014-05-15 
1       xxx  2014-05-20     2014-05-25   
4       yyy  2014-04-20     2014-04-21
```

now i have sql query like :

```
select * from leave where datefrom>='2014-05-01' and dateto<='2014-05-31'
```

so now i want output :

```
userid name total_leave_days
1      xxx   12
4      yyy   2

(2014-05-10 - 2014-05-15 )=6 days
(2014-05-20 - 2014-05-25 )=6 days
total = 12 days for useid 1
(2014-04-20 - 2014-04-21)= 2 days for userid 4
```

how can i calculate this total days .?

Comment: warning: 2014-05-10 - 2014-05-15 equals 5. You are counting "durations" and assuming 2014-05-15 is "at the end of the day"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    USERID, 
    NAME, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(day, DATEFROM, DATETO)+1) total_leave_days
From leave 
group by USERID, NAME
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38408/1)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that you need "+1" to emulate the expected calculations because there is an inherent assumption of ""start of day" for the Start date and "end of day" for end date - but dbms's don't think that way. a date is always stored as "start of day".

```
select
        USERID
      , name
      , sum( datediff(day,DATEFROM,DATETO) + 1 ) as leave_days
from leavetable
group by
        USERID
      , name
```

produces this:

```
| USERID | NAME | LEAVE_DAYS |
|--------|------|------------|
|      1 |  xxx |         12 |
|      4 |  yyy |          2 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebe5d/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DateDiff`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

```
SELECT UserID, Name, SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateFrom, DateTo) + 1) AS total_leave_days
FROM leave
WHERE datefrom >= '2014-05-01' AND dateto <= '2014-05-31'
GROUP BY UserID, Name
```

The `+ 1` ,of course, is because `DATEDIFF` will return the exclusive count, where it sounds like you want the inclusive number of days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select userid, name, sum (1 + datediff(day,datefrom,dateto)) as total_leave_days
from leaves
where datefrom>='2014-05-01' and dateto<='2014-05-31'
group by userid, name
```

This will sum the total leaves per `userid`. Note that `datediff` will give you 5 days difference for the range 2014-05-10 to 2014-05-15, so we need to add 1 to the result to get 6 days i.e. range inclusive of both ends.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VQW67097)